# Why is htop not aviable for Ubuntu touch?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, monitoring, htop

I recently noticed some UI-refreshrate-drops on my Nexus4 running Ubuntu Touch and wanted to see if I could find a process standing out in cpu usage etc. I wanted to install **`htop`** in the console app, but it couldn't be found. I researched this and it seems that htop is not available *on purpose*.

Why is this? And, if you know, can you suggest me any other monitoring tool, cli (preferred) or app for touch (despite `top`)?

Comment: It might just be that the scrolling feature is hard to integrate to Touch. An alternative is actually the graphical tool, System Monitor. It's built in.

Comment: @Zacharee1 Really?? Where can I find it?

Comment: I think you can just search for it.

Comment: It actually might not come preinstalled, but it is available on the Software Center.

Comment: Can't find it in Ubuntu Store. You say Software Center - Do you mean the same?

Comment: Yes. If you can't find it, try slowly dragging from the right edge of the screen.

Comment: Now I'm a bit confused... :-) `apt-get` says `E: Package 'gnome-system-monitor' has no installation candidate` and doesn't find `system-monitor`. Maybe I should also mention I'm on the stable branch.

Comment: What do you mean? You tried the gesture?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22997/discussion-between-peter-nerlich-and-zacharee1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sudo su -
cd /home/phablet/Downloads
```

*download deb file, e.g: from debian wheezy repositories:*

```
wget http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/h/htop/htop_1.0.1-1_armhf.deb
```

*remount root filesystem to read-write (I use the bellow command on my bq aquaris. Your filesystem name you can find by* `df -h /`)

```
mount /dev/mmcvlk0p6 -o remount,rw
dpkg -i htop_1.0.1-1_armhf.deb
```

Comment: Is this already tested on a mobile device?

Comment: yes, it is working on my phone bq Aquaris e4.5. (Ubuntu 14.10 (r21))

Comment: Yay, it works! Sorry that I waited for your feedback before testing anything, I wanted to have a minimal chance of breaking the system. On a PC I wouldn't hesitate that much, but on the phone I'd be uncomfortable with doing recovery and stuff...

Comment: NOTE: The bq m10 can dissable cpu cores when they aren't being used, so htop will show a diffrent amount of cores dependeing on how many are needed. If you want to update the number of cores you have to restart htop.